# Using font BinnerD in my WebSite

Tags: fonts

Is possible to use the font BinnerD in a website ? I tryed to use it in css,html but no luck.

Fonts for the web are limited?

Thanks!!

Comment: Have any of these answers helped you? If not what further information can we provide? Is so could you please mark the best answer as accepted. This rewards the answerer and moves this question off the unanswered list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer,

Not unless the user already has the font installed, in the font-family attribute of the CSS file you can and should specify multiple fonts. The web browser will look through this list and pick the first font that the user has installed. e.g.

```
font-family:Arial,Liberation Sans,DejaVu Sans,sans-serif;
```

will first use Arial if not found it will use Liberation Sans if not found will use DejaVu Sans and if not found will use sans-serif.

More Complex answer
More browsers are starting to enable downloadable fonts where you specify where the browser can download the font you want it to use e.g.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Kimberley";
  src: url(http://www.princexml.com/fonts/larabie/ »
  kimberle.ttf) format("truetype");
}
h1 { font-family: "Kimberley", sans-serif }
```

However to distribute fonts in this manner you need to licence the font from its producer. It is usally a different licence for producing print work or images and distibuting the font itself. Also browser support is far from universal.

EDIT: A good [reference on WebFonts](http://webfonts.info/wiki/index.php?title=What_are_webfonts%3F) i.e. downloadable fonts [http://webfonts.info](http://webfonts.info/wiki/index.php?title=What_are_webfonts%3F)

Answer (score 0):

Possible? Probably. Just convert it to a web font and upload it to your server so you can access it with a URL from your CSS.

Legal? Probably not. Fonts are copyrighted and licensed. To avoid hazzle, check what you're allowed to do before trying something like that.

Other options: Check the [free fonts from Google](http://code.google.com/webfonts) or the commercial [Typekit](http://typekit.com/).